# Raspberry pi is unable to reach gateway

Tags: ip, ethernet, raspberry-pi3, gateway

Recently we brought raspberry pi 3b.Beginning we used to access the internet using an ethernet cable and it used to connect properly but now raspberry pi is not able to reach the gateway itself and it's taking its default IP address i.e 169.xxx.xxx.xx.
what would be the issue?we tried to reinstalling the operating system again the same issue .it worked for one day after that same problem.so please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a windows computer available, open cmd and run the following command:

```
ipconfig
```

note down the values that display. Now on your pi, enter the command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will open the network interfaces file. Look for the line similar to 'inet eth0 inet manual' Then remove this line and everything to do with the eth0 interface, since we are going to start over.

in the interfaces file, add the following section:

```
auto eth0
inet eth0 inet static
       address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       network 255.255.255.0
       gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Replace the x in address with the first 3 groups of the value taken from the windows system. For example, if the ip address on the windows system was 192.168.0.221, enter 192.168.0.xxx

The last group of xxx for address should be something unique to everything else on your network.

'gateway' should be whatever the gateway value in windows was (assuming these machines are on the same network)

[Ctrl]+[x], Save changes

reboot via

```
sudo reboot
```

once the system has rebooted

```
ifconfig eth0
```

should list the new settings. Test them by pinging the below address (google)

```
sudo ping 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: The Above procedure didn't work.Raspberry pi is not able to take static IP.

Comment: @VishalkumarUppin you are quite correct, I had accidentally forgotten to put in the auto eth0 line

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to figure it out after trial and error method.                                I have missed "auto eth0" before the iface statement i.e

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

network 255.255.255.0

gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8